# How to sum from certain rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datagridview

I'm trying to display how many items sold during certain date.
The sales detail data looks about this

| SalesID | DetailID | Items | Quantity | salesDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | noodles | 1 | 17/02/2021 |
| 0 | 1 | burger | 1 | 17/02/2021 |
| 0 | 2 | salad | 1 | 17/02/2021 |
| 1 | 3 | fries | 1 | 18/02/2021 |
| 2 | 4 | noodles | 1 | 18/02/2021 |
| 2 | 5 | noodles | 1 | 18/02/2021 |
| 3 | 6 | fries | 1 | 19/02/2021 |
| 4 | 7 | noodles | 1 | 19/02/2021 |
| 5 | 8 | noodles | 1 | 20/02/2021 |

It was joined from other tables, viewed basically like above.
The final items sold table would search entry between [userInputDate1]and[userInputDate2] and simplify it.
Here is what supposed to show when user input 17/02/21 and 18/02/21.

| Items | ItemsSold |
| --- | --- |
| noodles | 3 |
| burger | 1 |
| salad | 1 |
| salad | 1 |

I've tried linq query

```
SELECT        Items, SUM(Quantity) AS TQuantity
FROM            PosView
WHERE        (salesDate > @userInputDate1) AND (salesDate < @userInputDate2)
GROUP BY Items
```

but it wont show in the datagridview.

I'm going to programmatically count the items in the datagridview using for /foreach if i dont find simpler solution

Comment: The SQL you have *is* the simplest solution. What does *"it wont show in the datagridview."* mean?

Comment: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Comment: Is the problem purely because you are using `>` and `<`? There are no `date` values that are **greater** than `20210217` *and* **less than** `20210218`. Should you actually be using `>=` ad `<=`? What you have is akin to asking something for an integer value between 3 and 4, excluding 3 and 4. There are no other integers between those two numbers.

Comment: If we *do* change your expressions to `>=` and `<=` the data set works fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ff7e9f14ea9a6757907e9c49c0160dbc).

Comment: Yes, but it still show that error in datagridview. It works when i preview it in query builder with 2 columns. The problem is when i preview it in the dataset's tableadapters, it shows the original table's all column, yet only 2 columns is filled. That's probably what causing the error, since it was different table than the original

Comment: Then that's what you should be asking about in your question. Include the error, and fix your SQL.

Comment: "I've tried linq query" - show the linq query you tried.

Answer (score 0):

See following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
namespace ConsoleApplication181
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("SalesID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("DetailID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Items", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("salesDate", typeof(DateTime));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {0, 0, "noodles",1, DateTime.ParseExact("17/02/2021", "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {0, 1, "burger",1, DateTime.ParseExact("17/02/2021", "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {0, 2, "salad",1, DateTime.ParseExact("17/02/2021", "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 3, "fries",1, DateTime.ParseExact("18/02/2021", "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, 4, "noodles",1, DateTime.ParseExact("18/02/2021", "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, 5, "noodles",1, DateTime.ParseExact("18/02/2021", "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3, 6, "fries",1, DateTime.ParseExact("19/02/2021", "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4, 7, "noodles",1, DateTime.ParseExact("19/02/2021", "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5, 8, "noodles",1, DateTime.ParseExact("20/02/2021", "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)});

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("Items", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("ItemsSold", typeof(int));

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Items")).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] {group.Key, group.Count()});
            }

        }
 
    }
 
}
```